# Bitwise_and mask error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Hello I tried to use `bitwise_and` from opencv with a camera but I recieved this error:

> imgMask = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask) cv2.error:
> OpenCV(4.5.4-dev)
> D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:230:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) &&
> _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

mask = np.zeros((480,640),dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.circle(mask,(320,240),125,(255),-1)
#mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
while (captura.isOpened()):
  ret,frame = captura.read()
  frame = cv2.resize(frame,(480,640))
  
  if ret == True:
    imgMask = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)
    cv2.imshow('video',imgMask)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
      break
  else: break
captura.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: mask = cv2.circle(mask,(480,640),125,(255),-1) try this

Comment: the same error, I think is the mask of zero

Comment: your resize parametes are backwards. try `frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))`

Answer (score 2):

I think check your frame and mask shapes first. If they are same you can try this;

```
imgMask = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask[:,:,2])
```

in stead of

```
imgMask = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)
```